# os.scandir does not list all entries in directory

Tags: python, file, directory, operating-system

While using either `os.scandir` or `os.listdir` to get a list of all filenames in the specified folder, I only get some returned. The folder contains about 84.000 .jpg images, and file names are just numbers (1, 2, 3, etc...)

Expected output: `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg` etc.

Returned output: `1.jpg`, `100.jpg`, `1000.jpg`, `10000.jpg`, `10001.jpg`, etc.

```
with os.scandir('path/to/images') as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.name)
```

I think it might be that the folder has trouble opening, and therefore initially only returns some results instead of all. Suggestions are very welcome

Comment: What you're getting is a list in alphabetic order. Do `print(len(entries))` and I bet you'll get the ~84,000 count you were expecting.

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/): _entries are yielded in system-dependent order_

Comment: If you _know_ the names of the files already, why do you need to use `os.scandir()` to get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the entries are listed, however, they are sorted differently. The files are sorted alphabetically - and not by their numerical value - in this case. When you sort alphabetically, this would be an example order:

- b
- ba
- baa
- bb
- c
- ca

This is the same rule being applied to numbers:

- 1
- 10
- 100
- 11
- 2
- 20

Everything is listed, but they come later in the list.

Comment: Thanks, I had printed a selection and checked whether all the files were there, the first images must be mentioned later and thus not be included in my selection...